# tkinter: How to apply customized ttk stylename that is defined in one class to other classes

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I would like to apply customized stylenames defined in a class to widgets found in other classes. How can I implement this?

Below is a test script for consideration. I would like to apply stylenames `'page.TFrame'` and `'press.TButton'` to classes `Page1` and `Page2`

**Test script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# tkinter modules
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class App(ttk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **options):
        # Extract key and value from **options using Python3 "pop" function:
        #   pop(key[, default])
        self.style = options.pop('style',ttk.Style())
        self.bg0   = options.pop('background1','light grey')
        self.bg1   = options.pop('background2','grey')
        self.fg0   = options.pop('fg_link','black')
        self.fg1   = options.pop('fg_text','white')
        self.font  = options.pop('font',tkFont.Font(family='Nimbus Roman No9 L',
                                 size='10', weight='normal'))

        # Initialise App Frame
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='self.TFrame')
        self.__setFont()
        self.__setStyle()
        self.__createPages(parent)


    def __setFont(self):
        """Set the fonts to be used to build the App GUI."""
        self.fontTitle = self.font.copy()
        self.fontTitle.config(size='30')
        self.font.config(size='13')


    def __setStyle(self):
        """Customise ttk styles""" 
        ## LoginPanel styles
        self.style.configure('self.TFrame', background='pink')
        self.style.configure('page.TFrame', background=self.bg0)
        self.style.configure('press.TButton', font=self.fontTitle,
                             background=self.bg0, foreground=self.fg0,
                             relief='raised')


    def __createPages(self, parent):
        """Create Login and NewUser pages."""
        self._frames = {}
        for F in (Page1, Page2):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=self)
            self._frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.showFrame("Page1")

        parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def showFrame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self._frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()



class Page1(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='What to write here?')

        b1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Page 1',,
                        style='What to write here?')
        b1 .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        b2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Goto Page 2?',
                        command=lambda: parent.showFrame("Page2"))
        b2 .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')


class Page2(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='What to write here?')

        b1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Page 2',
                        style='What to write here?')
        b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        b2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Goto Page 1?',
                        command=lambda: parent.showFrame("Page1"))
        b2 .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x350+300+300')
    BG1 = 'blue'
    BG0 = 'lightblue'
    FG0 = 'white'
    FG1 = 'light blue'

    app = App(root, background1=BG0, background2=BG1,
                  fg_link=FG1, fg_text=FG0)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out and surprisingly the answer is a simple one.

**Answer:** I just have to pass the style attribute parameter containing the customized style names that I want to use to the other classes that needs to use those style names. In my script, the attribute parameter that needs to be passed is `self.style`. Hope this answer helps others with the same need.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# tkinter modules
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class App(ttk.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **options):
        # Extract key and value from **options using Python3 "pop" function:
        #   pop(key[, default])
        self.style = options.pop('style',ttk.Style())
        self.bg0   = options.pop('background1','light grey')
        self.bg1   = options.pop('background2','grey')
        self.fg0   = options.pop('fg_link','black')
        self.fg1   = options.pop('fg_text','white')
        self.font  = options.pop('font',tkFont.Font(family='Nimbus Roman No9 L',
                                 size='10', weight='normal'))

        # Initialise App Frame
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='self.TFrame')
        self.__setFont()
        self.__setStyle()
        self.__createPages(parent)


    def __setFont(self):
        """Set the fonts to be used to build the App GUI."""
        self.fontTitle = self.font.copy()
        self.fontTitle.config(size='30')
        self.font.config(size='13')


    def __setStyle(self):
        """Customise ttk styles""" 
        ## LoginPanel styles
        self.style.configure('self.TFrame', background='pink')
        self.style.configure('page.TFrame', background=self.bg0)
        self.style.configure('press.TButton', font=self.fontTitle,
                             background=self.bg1, foreground=self.fg0,
                             relief='raised')


    def __createPages(self, parent):
        """Create Login and NewUser pages."""
        self._frames = {}
        for F in (Page1, Page2):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=self, style=self.style) #pass style attribute
            self._frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.showFrame("Page1")

        parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    def showFrame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self._frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()



class Page1(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, style): #added `style` argument
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='page.TFrame') #call the stylename

        b1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Page 1', style='press.TButton') #call the stylename
        b1 .grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        b2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Goto Page 2?',
                        command=lambda: parent.showFrame("Page2"))
        b2 .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')


class Page2(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, style): #added `style` argument
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style='page.TFrame') #call the stylename

        b1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Page 2', style='press.TButton') #call the stylename
        b1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        b2 = ttk.Button(self, text='Goto Page 1?',
                        command=lambda: parent.showFrame("Page1"))
        b2 .grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x350+300+300')
    BG1 = 'blue'
    BG0 = 'lightblue'
    FG0 = 'white'
    FG1 = 'light blue'

    app = App(root, background1=BG0, background2=BG1,
                  fg_link=FG1, fg_text=FG0)
    app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```